# Apollo client useQuery fails to return cached data when variables are changed

Tags: apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

Consider the following queries

```
useQuery(POSTS, {
  variables: {
    offset: currPage * 20
  }
})
```

where `currPage` is a React local state variable. It will get updated when user paginates

**Intended outcome:**

When `currPage=1`, new data is fetched, when `currPage=2`, new data is fetched... When user paginates to the previous page (page 1), because query with `currPage=1` is already fetched, it should just read the cache

**Actual outcome:**

When user paginates from page 1 to page 2, new data for page 2 is fetched, however, when user paginates back to page 1, cache is not read, data is still displayed for page 2

**Versions**

Apollo client version: `@apollo/client: ^3.0.0-beta.14`

This bug is also reported in Apollo client GitHub: https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/5659

Comment: This would indeed seem to be a bug, unless you're setting a different fetch policy globally through the client instance.